# How to activate Einstein bots in a new sfdx scratch org?

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, einstein, bots

I tried a lot of combinations, but not matter what I do, the "Einstein bots" menu of my generated scratch orgs only targets to "Contact support to activate Einstein Bots"

According to the trailhead, we need **Service Cloud**, **Live Agent**, **Knownledge** .

I also saw the value **Chatbot** in the (not very documented) [Features page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm)

All of them are activated in my my project-scratch-def.json file , but as result I continue to be unable to use Einstein Bots in my scratch org.

```
{
    "orgName": "DNV_NicoV_Home112_Bot3",
    "edition": "Developer",
    "country": "FR",
    "language": "en_US",
    "username": "nvuillamy@dnv_xxxxxx-scratch.com",
    "adminEmail": "nvuillam@xxx.com",
    "features": [
        "AddCustomApps:10",
        "AddCustomTabs:30",
        "API",
        "AuthorApex",
        "Chatbot",
        "Communities",
        "ContactsToMultipleAccounts",
        "DebugApex",
        "EinsteinAssistant",
        "Knowledge",
        "LightningServiceConsole",
        "LiveAgent",
        "LiveMessage",
        "MultiCurrency",
        "ServiceCloud",
        "SiteDotCom",
        "Sites",
        "StateAndCountryPicklist"
    ],
    "settings": {
        "orgPreferenceSettings": {
            "chatterEnabled": true,
            "networksEnabled": true,
            "s1DesktopEnabled": true,
            "s1EncryptedStoragePref2": false,
            "translation": true
        },
        "liveAgentSettings": {
            "enableLiveAgent": true
        },
        "securitySettings": {
            "sessionSettings": {
                "enableSMSIdentity": false,
                "identityConfirmationOnTwoFactorRegistrationEnabled": false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: which is the API version in your project definition file?

Comment: have you tried to create Enterprise scratch org instead of Developer edition one?

Comment: just one more suggestion, have you tried to create a scratch org from an org where Einstein bots are enabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*** UPDATE ***

It now appears to be possible to create scratch orgs with Einstein Bots enabled. For ease, this is the project-scratch-def file I used:

```
{
    "edition": "Enterprise",
    "features": ["ServiceCloud","Chatbot","CPQ","Communities","Knowledge","LiveAgent","LightningServiceConsole","LiveMessage"],
    "settings": {
        "lightningExperienceSettings": {
            "enableS1DesktopEnabled": true
        },
        "mobileSettings": {
            "enableS1EncryptedStoragePref2": false
        },
        "communitiesSettings": {
            "enableNetworksEnabled": true
        },
        "omniChannelSettings": {
            "enableOmniChannel": true
        },
        "liveAgentSettings": {
          "enableLiveAgent": true
        }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Just to add to the updated answer by @weeden, the document makes the following statement: 

"To use this feature, turn on Enable Einstein Features in the Dev Hub org to accept the Terms of Service."

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm

Answer (score 0):

I think at the current release there is no possibility to automatically turn on Einstein bots on scratch orgs.

Instead, [as suggested in this knowledge article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000271298&type=1), you will have to download a form

> Download a copy of the Order Form Supplement for Einstein features
>   found here:
>   https://www.salesforce.com/content/dam/web/en_us/www/documents/legal/misc/order-form-supplement-for-einstein-features.pdf

Then have it signed

> Have the form signed by an authorized representative of your company.
>   Please be sure to include Account number(s) or orgID(s) for all orgs
>   that you want to have access to Einstein features. Org IDs can be
>   found by following these instructions:
>   https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000006019&type=1. Account
>   numbers appear on Salesforce invoices.

And file a Salesforce Support Case

> Log a Case with Support Go to Salesforce Help & Training and login
>   with your Salesforce credentials Click on the Feature Activation topic
>   and then on Einstein Bots category Scroll down and click Log a New
>   Case Enter “Enable Einstein” in the Subject line of the Case Enter a
>   Description, ensure the orgID is accurate and click the Submit button

The last step you might have to repeat for each and every scratch org which may be nasty.
However, you can change default duration of scratch org to maximum value of 30 days to ensure that the scratch org is still alive when Support would turn on Einstein bot feature for you on it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply... but we are a team of 10 people working in the same repo... so we can not log a case every time a new scratch org must be created :/ We also have Jenkins jobs generating automatically a scratch off at each pull request... so unfortunately this solution is not applicable :/

Comment: I'll wait for sfdc to make usable with DX the features they announce ^^

Comment: Probably you should open a case in Salesforce and confirm that this is not available and ask Salesforce what they would suggest

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to create scratch org with enabled Einstein Bots feature now. And you can't enable it manually.

You need to create regular developer edition org or Trailhead Playground to have the possibility to enable it.