# Enabling servicecloud feature for scratchorg,

Tags: salesforcedx, servicecloud, developer-edition, service-console

Have enabled the servicecloud,LightningServiceConsole feature in scratchorg, but still not seeing service console and service setup in my scratch org

```
  "orgName": "Demo company",
  "edition": "Developer",
  "features": ["LightningServiceConsole","LiveAgent","Chatbot","ServiceCloud"],
```

Is there anything else I need to lookout for.

Comment: Have you also included the "settings" sections in your scratch org def file? like - 
"botSettings": {"enableBots": true} You might want to refer https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/249843/how-to-activate-einstein-bots-in-a-new-sfdx-scratch-org/283149#283149

Answer (score 1):

After changing edition from "Developer" -> "Enterprise"

Every feature and corresponding started enabled.